# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Adding member variable not a part of a database column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I add member variables not part of a database column? From searching I saw something called @Transient for java, but nothing for C#. I am also using the entity framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 [NotMapped]
 public string Whatever { get; set; }
```

Can't believe you haven't found this.